# On submit text box deleted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to remove `<span class="reqMsg">* Email is required</span` on Submit if it validates. For example If nothing is entered in the first fieldbox display the error and if something is displayed how do I make the error gone?

[My JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J7Z5P/):

```
MY JS:

function elem(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};


window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector("#RadioGroup1_0").click();


    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.onsubmit = function (e) {
        var rules = [
        ['first-name', elem('first-name').value.length > 0],
        ['last-name', elem('last-name').value.length > 0],
        ['email', elem('email').value.length > 0 && /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(elem('email').value)],
        ['phone', elem('phone').value.length > 7 && elem('phone').value.length < 11 && /^(\+\d{1,2})?[\d ()-]+$/.test(elem('phone').value)]

    ];

    function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

        function alpha(e) {
            var k;
            document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
            return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8);
        }

        var valid = true;
        var firstFocus = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            if (!rules[i][1]) {
                valid = false;
                var parent = elem(rules[i][0]).parentNode;
                parent.children[2].style.display = "inline";
                if (firstFocus == null) firstFocus = parent.children[1];
            }
        }
        if (!valid) {
            firstFocus.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
}


function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
    try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        } else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (charCode === 8)) return true;
        else return false;
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}


var specialKeys = new Array();
specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
function IsNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
    //document.getElementById("phone").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
    return ret;
}

//var valid = email.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]){1,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/);
```

Comment: Duplicate thread of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511090/this-doesnt-seem-right-javascript-isnt-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510490/how-to-show-a-required-message-next-to-input-with-javascript

Comment: @Newbie Are you serious dude? Not even close of a duplicate. If you're not going to help/support stop being annoying.

Comment: Three of them were asking how to hide the error messages if it is validated. I don't see any difference there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the successful `return true` statement  of `form.onsubmit,` insert the following line

```
document.querySelector(".reqMsg").style.display = "none";
```

It will hide the error message.

If you want to hide all the error messages

```
var errorMessages = document.querySelectorAll(".reqMsg");
for(var dom in errorMessages) { 
  errorMessages[dom].style.display = "none";
}
```

If you want to clear the error message as well then use

```
document.querySelector(".reqMsg").innerHTML = ""
```

For individual field validation:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            var parent = elem(rules[i][0]).parentNode;
            if (!rules[i][1]) {
                valid = false;
                parent.children[2].style.display = "inline";
                if (firstFocus == null) firstFocus = parent.children[1];
            } else {
                parent.children[2].style.display = "none";
            }

        }
```

Hope its useful to you :)

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for helping me out! Although only first name fieldbox resets nothing else?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".reqMsg").style.display = "none";` Use the following statement

Comment: That just stopped working altogether, now all the errors next to the fieldbox it self have dissapeard :(.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it. Replace the replace that line with the following code `var errorMessages = document.querySelectorAll(".reqMsg");
for(var dom in errorMessages) { 
  errorMessages[dom].style.display = "none";
}`

Comment: Hi there again, still doesn't seem to be working :/ Can you edit it in JSFIDDLE

Comment: The above code itself will work. Please check this one : http://jsbin.com/koqerupe/1/

Comment: The reqMsg error's themself don't dissapear?

Comment: On submission, if the form is valid the error messages will be removed from the page.  http://jsbin.com/koqerupe/1/edit

Comment: I understand what you mean, but in your first answer is it possible to do it like that but for all of them? E.g First name is invalid and then you write something in it resubmit and the error is gone?

Comment: Please check the updated answer above. Also here is the working model as per your requirement http://jsbin.com/koqerupe/3/edit

Comment: OH MY GOD I COULD KISS YOU RIGHT NOW, THANK YOU SO MCUH!!!!

Comment: You are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the span class this css `display : none` on success.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: well,in your email validation function you can also add $(".reqmsg").css("display", "none");    to hide the span

Comment: Didn't seem to work :/

Comment: $(".reqMsg").css({display: "none"}); This worked for me..and in the stylesheet do include .reqMsg { display :block;}

Comment: Where did you input the code?

Comment: in your function alpha() ,theres a line             parent.children[2].style.display = "inline";change that to
parent.children[2].style.display = "none";

Comment: Didn't seem to work if you could edit it on JSFIDDLE that would be great for some reason it won't work for me?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/udeIScEC57HJRV8Z9b03?p=preview            ..check this

Comment: I see what you mean, but what I need is basically an error in a fieldbox without anything in it or the incorrect validation and then when they've fixed that the error should dissapear

Comment: so you need to display a error msg when the email you entered is not valid right??In that case why not give input type="email" instead of text

Comment: Because I'm coding it in XHTML 1.0

Comment: if you want to highlight it,why not give                 $("#email").css({"border-color": "red"});
if the email entered is not valid

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this what you need

```
if (!rules[i][1]) {
    valid = false;
    var parent = elem(rules[i][0]).parentNode;
    parent.children[2].style.display = "inline";
    if (firstFocus == null) firstFocus = parent.children[1];
} else {
    parent.children[2].style.display = "none";
}
```